# てらんない- can't bear to do ~

Tags: words

When we use ていられない, it means that we don't bother or care to do something.

> アさん)ああ、危なくて見てらんない！
>   イさん) もう黙っていらんない。注意しよう。
>   A) Oh no, I can't bear to see him doing dangerous things.
>  
>   B) me too, I can't bear keeping quiet. I better warn him.
>
> So 遅いなあ！もう待ってらんないので、先に帰る！
>   It is so late! I don't care anymore so I don't want to wait and go home first.
>
> 忙しくてテレビなんか見てらんない。
>   Because I am busy, I can't bear to watch any further. (Am I right to translate this sentence??)

One more thing, based on the last sentence, what does なんか really mean in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: なんか is often used in negative sentences. If you really want to translate it, it means something like “such as”. など and たり have a similar function, too.

Comment: What's your question? Is it only about "one more thing", about なんか? If so, why do you talk about てらんない in your question title?

Answer (score 0):

なんか in this context is used to emphasize the contemptuous feeling towards the object placed before it. So, because this person is busy, she doesn't have time to watch TV, which this person seems to see as a waste of time.

I'm not aware of appropriate direct translation of this word in English, so you may need to get creative in order to express the negative feeling. Something like "I'm too busy to be wasting my time watching TV" would work.